# api/issues/search response has 'author' field only when logged in

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web

The 'author' field is missing when i invoke 'api/issues/search' in a web explorer. Then i log in as admin in Sonarqube and the 'author' field is available using the same web explorer.
Is it a configuration issue for the Sonarqube users?

http://localhost:9000/api/server/version
7.4.0.18908

Answer (score 0):

To whom might step into this issuse, the simplest solution is to authenticate before, this should do the trick in Groovy

```
def addr       = "${sonarUrl}"
def authString = "user:password".getBytes().encodeBase64().toString()

def conn = addr.toURL().openConnection()
conn.setRequestProperty( "Authorization", "Basic ${authString}" )
conn.content.text
```